# CSS Rule for Flagging comments bumps layout by 1px

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've noticed on Programmmers.SE that when you hover over the `flag this comment` button it bumps the surrounding container by 1px. After inspecting the css, I noticed these rules in all.css:

```
.flag-off {
    background-position: -2px -741px;
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
}
.flag-on {
    background-position: -2px -712px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}
```

I think the second one should read:

```
.flag-on {
    background-position: -2px -712px;
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
}
```

To prevent the layout from jumping.

Comment: I'm looking into this. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.